# Error with variables when requiring from url

Tags: php

Note; The problem is not in require or include.( it's in variables) while requiring or including from URl
I am facing an strange error as following:

```
require_once "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/engine/header.php';
```

This is causing errors with variables

> Undefined Variables

While this :

```
require_once '/engine/header.php';
```

Doesn't cause any problem!

Sorry if have misspelled anything or written not understandable words.

Comment: Why does this isn't being helped?

Comment: `require*()` functions are internal path only.

Comment: Try printing or echo'ing $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] to see if it resolves to what you expect.

Comment: Refer to http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php on how to do it correctly (that page has all the answers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is located [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php).

> If "URL include wrappers" are enabled in PHP, you can specify the file to be included using a URL (via HTTP or other supported wrapper - see Supported Protocols and Wrappers for a list of protocols) instead of a local pathname. If the target server interprets the target file as PHP code, variables may be passed to the included file using a URL request string as used with HTTP GET. This is not strictly speaking the same thing as including the file and having it inherit the parent file's variable scope; the script is actually being run on the remote server and the result is then being included into the local script.

This means if you include a URL, it will be an independent PHP execution outside of your current scope. You would need to pass the variables via the `$_GET` superglobal.

If the `include`/`require` is absolute/relative file paths, you would be able to access the variables via that scope.

Comment: Exactly! How did I forgot that! Thanks, aziz.

Answer (score 1):

You can only include URLs if URL include wrappers are enabled, so check if `allow_url_include` is set to true in your php config.

Comment: You can pass a URL of a remote file, but there are limitations.
See http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: Actually, I didn't say the problem is with including or requiring, refused answer.

Comment: @AhmedAlaa You don't refuse an answer on this website, you either vote up or down + accept and answer. Learn how to use stackoverflow @ http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Aziz, I refused answer as a result of misunderstand!

Answer (score 0):

When you access a `.php` file through the webserver, the webserver executes the file, and the response that's sent to the client is the output of the script, not the script's source code. But `require` expects to read PHP source code from the file, so it can execute it in the context of the current script.

So unless `header.php` takes special measures to output PHP source code when it's being accessed remotely, trying to require it using a URI is not going to work correctly.